# need to update a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update the table 1 in the Old Value attribute. can we use select in the set? I do not see any problem at all to do it...

Code:

```
declare @oldvalue int 
set @oldvalue=1 
UPDATE [table_1]            
SET OldValue=(SELECT Description 
             FROM table2 
             WHERE OldValue=@oldvalue)          
WHERE ChangedField='UAC' and OldValue=@OldValue and  convert(date, LastChangeDate) ='2018-05-05' and id=875304
```

It throws this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>
> > , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

why?? the part  (SELECT Description 
             FROM table2 
             WHERE OldValue=@oldvalue)
delivers only one record (I have tried for values from 1 to 10 ).

Comment: Perhaps value 11 returns more than one record.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the problem and just work around it by using `top`:

```
UPDATE [table_1]            
    SET OldValue = (SELECT TOP (1) t2.Description 
                    FROM table2 t2
                    WHERE t2.OldValue = @oldvalue
                   )          
    WHERE ChangedField = 'UAC' and OldValue = @OldValue and
          convert(date, LastChangeDate) = '2018-05-05' and id = 875304;
```

You can diagnose the problem by looking for the duplicates:

```
select t2.OldValue
from table2 t2
group by t2.OldValue
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you Update a Value using a subquery, you should make sure that the Sub Query returns only 1 row, otherwise, you will get this error.

So you may try any of the below

**Method# 1** - Use Top

```
DECLARE @oldvalue INT;
SET @oldvalue = 1;
UPDATE [table_1]
  SET
      OldValue =
(
    SELECT TOP [Description]
    FROM table2
    WHERE OldValue = @oldvalue
)
WHERE ChangedField = 'UAC'
      AND OldValue = @OldValue
      AND CONVERT(DATE, LastChangeDate) = '2018-05-05'
      AND id = 875304;
```

**Method# 2 -**  Use Join (*Recommended*)

```
DECLARE @oldvalue INT;
SET @oldvalue = 1;

update t1
    set OldValue = t2.[Description]
    FROM [table_1] t1
       inner join table2 t1
          on t1.OldValue = t2.OldValue
          AND t1.ChangedField = 'UAC'
      AND t1.OldValue = @OldValue
      AND t1.CONVERT(DATE, LastChangeDate) = '2018-05-05'
      AND t1.id = 875304;
```